# Error PLS-00049: bad bind variable in trigger and can't figure out why?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER delete_pictures
AFTER DELETE ON "Pictures"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM "Photograph"
  WHERE Photograph.ID_Picture=:old.ID_Picture;
  DELETE FROM "Painting"
  WHERE Painting.ID_Picture=:old.ID_Picture;
END;
```

I have this sql trigger and when I try to add it to my database I get an PLS-00049: bad bind variable at booth OLD variables. I am not that good with sql yet and don't really know why it happens and how to correct it I looked at other cases of this but it did not really help me with this case. Basically what I am trying to do is if the parent element is deleted I want to delete his child too.

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way to do what you want.  You are looking for `on delete cascade` foreign key triggers.

```
alter table photograph
    add constraint fk_photograph_picture
        foreign key (picture) references picture(id_picture) on delete cascade;

alter table painting
    add constraint fk_painting_picture
        foreign key (picture) references picture(id_picture) on delete cascade;
```

[Here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php) is a resource on understanding cascading delete.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, there is no column called `ID_PICTURE` in the table `Pictures` (not the uppercase spelling of `ID_PICTURE`).

It is a bad practice to use lowercase names in Oracle. Oracle is case-sensitive. But unquoted names in SQL statements are automatically converted to uppercase. So if your really use lowercase letters in table and column names, you must always put them in double quotes.

Your trigger should probably read:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER delete_pictures
AFTER DELETE ON "Pictures"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM "Photograph"
  WHERE "Photograph"."ID_Picture" = :old."ID_Picture";
  DELETE FROM "Painting"
  WHERE "Painting"."ID_Picture" = :old."ID_Picture";
END;
```

But it would be much easier to not use lowercase names and double quotes in the first place.